# Using tokenfield.js but now my javascript doesn't work anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using tokenfield.js on a simple textbox where I have a javascript which adds text to it on click. But now I have installed tokenfield.js on it, and the javascript doesn't work anymore.

Tokenfield.js in my document:

```
  <script>

$(function() {
//Tokenfield

$('#tokenfield-jQUI').tokenfield({
  autocomplete: {
    source: ['red','blue','green','yellow','violet','brown','purple','black','white'],
    delay: 100

  },
  showAutocompleteOnFocus: true

});
});
</script>
```

Javascript for adding text to text box on click

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function addtext() {
var newtext = document.myform.inputtext.value;
if (document.myform.placement[1].checked) {
    document.myform.outputtext.value = "";
    }
document.myform.outputtext.value += newtext;
    }
    </script>
```

form:

```
<form name="myform">
 <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5"><tr>
 <td><textarea name="inputtext"></textarea></td>
 <input type="radio" name="placement" value="append" checked> Add to Existing Text<br>
 <td><p><input type="radio" name="placement" value="replace"> Replace Existing Text<br>
 <input type="button" value="Add New Text" onClick="addtext();"></p>
 </td>
 <td><textarea name="outputtext"></textarea></td> 
 </tr></table>
 </form>
```

Comment: Any javascript error you are getting?

Comment: no. It seems like he doesn't see the function or something

Comment: can you post the javascript files which you included in the head section?